# how to post on facebook user's profile every time user logs in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

i'm a newbie to facebook app. development. As part of my term project i have to design an app.

i want to make a call to method 'feed dialogue' or want to post on user's wall, **every time user logs in to his account**.. which means i want to trigger my app. automatically every time user logs in........ or can my app. be triggered **automatically every time** user post some thing ??..... should i make my app. run in background.... or what should i do..??

give me some references or anything...

Thank you

Comment: Please don’t do such a thing at all – it would be very spammy.

Comment: @CBroe so.. is there any alternative for that...?? like can i schedule the posts and can post time to time...?